# How to get a WPF DataGrid to resort when a value changed?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` control in a C#, WPF Project.

The control sorts by a column so far so good, however when a value changes and emits `PropertyChanged` this does not make the DataGrid resort.

i.e. it only sorts when the column header is clicked but ignores all subsequent value changes and with time the list becomes disorganized until the user again clicks the column header.

a ugly workaround would be this:

```
if (sockGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Count > 0)
{
    sockGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Insert(0, sockGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.First());
    sockGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

But there must be a better way that would hopefully have also a much better performance?

So my question is: how can I get the `DataGrid` to auto-update the sorting when one of the listed items emitted a `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: Can you share your xaml code and viewmodel? You can achieve the resorting by using a `CollectionViewSource` in xaml

Comment: here is some of the source: https://pastebin.com/5xaeRKbH